# Aix compilation error due to #define

Tags: c, aix, xlc

"1506-221 (S) Initializer must be a valid constant expression."

In aix during compilation of header file i am facing this issue.

In the header file the source is like

`#define A(b) (a+b)`

like that.

wherever this macro "A"(Ex:A(5)) is used in source it throws the above error.

can anyone help me to solve this?

Edited:

in the header file

```
#define A(b) (a+b)
```

in the source file

```
struct a
{
   int a;
   int b;
} ain = {10, A(10)};
```

like this .

Comment: What is compilation of header? Are you using precompiled headers?

Comment: No,I am using one header file named a.h in that i defined like that.so in the source c file  whereever i used that macro it throws that error.other platforms like linux or solaris it worked ,only aix it is not working

Comment: please show how you "*use the macro*".

Comment: What is `a` and `b`? There are no variables `a` and `b` in your code that can be used in the initializer list. Or otherwise, how exactly do you think it makes sense to initialize a variable to 10 plus its own uninitialized value?

Comment: @Lundin: `b` is the marco argument, thus ok. Buit `a` is missing.

Comment: @Olaf, after the edit you can see that `a` is one of the structure fields. The OP thinks.

Comment: There's no point in speculating really, this is complete nonsense code.

Comment: @iharob: Which is not know in the global namespace. I'd actually be surprised if a `struct` initialiser is allowed to reference a struct-member that way in C.

Answer (score 1):

You can't initialize a structure with a non constant value, in this case you are using one of the structure fields I suppose but as it is your macro doesn't even know that since `a` isn't actually defined to be anything, try this instead

```
#define INIT_STRUCT(x, a, b) do {x->a = a; x->b = x->a + b} while (0);
```

and use it like this

```
struct a {int a; int b;};
INIT_STRUCT(&a, 10, 10);
```

**NOTE**: But please don't do this, instead just initialize it like this

```
a.a = 10;
a.b = a.a + 10;
```

or if you need to initialize many of these write a function instead.

Comment: No, don't write code like this, it is horrible, unreadable obfuscation.

Comment: @freeworld: Agreeing with Lundin, you should not use such constructs. Drop that macro approach and use designated initialisers.

Comment: @Lundin I agree, but this is what the OP wants. Still, it would be nice to leave a note telling them NOT TO DO THIS.